# Janus join videoroom get "Error setting ICE locally"

Tags: node.js, janus

I am creating my room with this part of my code:

```
const data = await janusRequest(
      {
        url: `/${session_id}/${handle_id}`,
        body: videoRoomRequestBody({
          request: VideoRoomValues.VIDEO_ROOM_CREATE_ROOM,
          room: group_video_chat_id,
          permanent: false,
          description: "Room for group video chat",
          is_private: false,
          audiolevel_ext: true,
          audiolevel_event: true,
          audio_active_packets: 100,
          audio_level_average: 25,
        }),
        plugin_data: true
      }
    )
```

and for example I send something like this using **postman** to my `NodeJS` based web

```
server:
{
    "pwd": "QjfvefknbnebQEDQWvswBFDb",
    "api_version": "1.0.0",
    "data": {
        "group_video_chat_id": "25",
        "event_url": "http://google.com"
    },
    "method": "createGroupVideoChat"
}
```

I get this response from Janus:

```
{
  janus: 'success',
  session_id: 6386148871430115,
  transaction: '',
  sender: 5767816649368815,
  plugindata: {
    plugin: 'janus.plugin.videoroom',
    data: { videoroom: 'created', room: 2, permanent: false }
  }
}
```

But when I want to join the created videoroom this part of my code runs successfully (joining the group)

```
const join_result = await janusRequest({
      url: `/${session_id}/${handle_id}`,
      body: videoRoomRequestBody(
        {
          request: VideoRoomValues.VIDEO_ROOM_USER_JOIN,
          room: group_video_chat_id,
          display: "sample",
          ptype: join_halted ? "subscriber" : "publisher"
        }
      ),
      plugin_data: true
    })
```

But sending the `SDP offer` request to the Janus:

```
if (join_result === true) {
      const tid = randomTransactionId(12)
      const offer_result = await janusRequest({
        url: `/${session_id}/${handle_id}`,
        body: videoRoomRequestBody(
          {
            request: VideoRoomValues.VIDEO_ROOM_CONFIGURE,
            audio: join_muted,
            video: join_halted,
          },
          {
            type: "offer",
            sdp: sdp_offer_data
          },
          tid
        )
      })
```

just contains a normal `ack`:

```
{
  janus: 'ack',
  session_id: 3151031963521719,
  transaction: 'OUdkZy8cS6hD'
}
```

But I want to get the `SDP answer`. I searched in the demos inspect network tab(run it locally in my local machine) and see that the browser sends a **GET** request to `/${session_id}?rid=${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}&maxev=10` and gets back the `SDP answer`. So I did it manually in my code:

```
const answer_result = await janusRequest({
              url: `/${session_id}?rid=${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}&maxev=10`,
              method: "get"
            }
          )
```

but there is nothing in the response. the response is empty!
I searched the Internet and see that the problem may be fixed with an extra `create` event to Janus with the `SDP offer` again. I tried it also:

```
const sdp_answer_result = await janusRequest({
          url: `/${session_id}/${handle_id}`,
          body: videoRoomRequestBody(
            {
              request: VideoRoomValues.VIDEO_ROOM_CREATE_ROOM,
            },
            {
              type: "offer",
              sdp: sdp_offer_data
            },
            tid
          ),
          plugin_data: true
        })
```

But I get `Error setting ICE locally` error.
It may be useful to note that after the join request (the request to my NodeJS app with postman) I do these steps in order: join to the group with `join` event > sending sdp and some other data to Janus with `configure` > send a `create` event again with the `sdp` => get the error. and in the janus container logs, I get:

```
Creating new session: 8793136254931427; 0x7fb1dc005390
Creating new handle in session 8793136254931427: 8511534556421310; 0x7fb1dc005390 0x7fb1dc005240
[ERR] [plugins/janus_videoroom.c:janus_videoroom_handler:9203] Missing mandatory element (feed)
[8511534556421310] Creating ICE agent (ICE Full mode, controlled)
[ERR] [plugins/janus_videoroom.c:janus_videoroom_handler:8737] Invalid request "configure" on unconfigured participant
[WARN] [8511534556421310] Agent already exists?
[ERR] [janus.c:janus_process_incoming_request:1541] Error setting ICE locally
```

these errors. How can I get the sdp answer from the janus service. How does the demo work as it can get the answer correctly.